# Magento2 Product Gallery Fotorama

Tags: magento2, gallery, fotorama-slider

I got a custom module where I load the images for the product.
You can select a image, now I want that this specific image is selected in the Gallery Fotorama.

So say for example standard it is showing a yellow mug, but you select in the custom module a green mug, the active image in the Fotorama has to change to the green mug.

Is this possible? So yes how should I do this?

I tried to set the classes through JavaScript, but this is a lot of hassle.

Is there a way that I can tell Fotorama what image has to be active?